# ERROR- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error, please help and thanks for all your ideas :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
>       at HTMLDivElement.
>
> happen at : bigImage.parentNode.removeChild(bigImage);
>               spinner.parentNode.removeChild(spinner);

this is my program simply remove images when click on each until there is only 1 image, then if the user click on the last image it will show the fullscreen image.

```
myArtlist.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    chooseArt(e);
}, false);

function chooseArt (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "IMG") {
        var numberOfImage = document.querySelectorAll("ul.grid li>img");
        var countImage = numberOfImage.length;
        console.log(numberOfImage);
        console.log(countImage);
        if (countImage > 1) {
            var myImage = event.target.parentNode;
            myImage.parentNode.removeChild(myImage);
        }
        if (countImage === 1) {
                    var overlay = document.querySelector("div.overlay");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        var imageSrc = event.target.src;
        var bigImage = document.createElement("img");
        bigImage.className = "bgImg";
        bigImage.src = imageSrc.substr(0,imageSrc.length-7) + ".jpg";
        overlay.appendChild(bigImage);

        var spinner = document.createElement("img");
        spinner.className = "spinner";
        spinner.src = "images/spinner.gif";
        overlay.appendChild(spinner);
        bigImage.addEventListener("load", function () {
            overlay.removeChild(spinner);
        }, false);

        overlay.addEventListener("click", function () {
            overlay.style.display = "none";
            bigImage.parentNode.removeChild(bigImage);
            spinner.parentNode.removeChild(spinner);
        }, false);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You take the parents parent here: `var myImage = event.target.parentNode;` are you sure that the image is not the target directly?

Comment: Which line? The callstack should tell you which line is failing. That will help you track it down.

Comment: Every time you call `chooseArt()` you add a new `bigImage` to the overlay, and add a click handler that removes it. But when you remove it you don't remove the click handler, so the next time you click you'll try to remove it again, but that will fail because `bigImage.parentNode` is `null`.